# eclipse plugin for format C code of enums

Tags: c, enums, eclipse-plugin, formatting

I'm looking for an Eclipse plugin that will format my C source codes, especially focusing on enum definitions.

For example:
Original code:

```
typedef enum _eDEVICE_SM_STATE
{
        eDEVICE_SM_STATE_NOT_INITIALISED                    //!< Not initialized
    ,   eDEVICE_SM_STATE_OFF                                //!< Off
    ,   eDEVICE_SM_STATE_START_UP                           //!< Start up
    ,   eDEVICE_SM_STATE_CONTROL                            //!< On
    ,   eDEVICE_SM_STATE_STANDBY                            //!< Standby
    ,   eDEVICE_SM_STATE_ERROR                              //!< Error
}eDEVICE_SM_STATE;
```

After formatting, I want:

```
typedef enum _eDEVICE_SM_STATE
{
    eDEVICE_SM_STATE_NOT_INITIALISED, //!< Not initialized
    eDEVICE_SM_STATE_OFF,             //!< Off
    eDEVICE_SM_STATE_START_UP,        //!< Start up
    eDEVICE_SM_STATE_CONTROL,         //!< On
    eDEVICE_SM_STATE_STANDBY,         //!< Standby
    eDEVICE_SM_STATE_ERROR,           //!< Error
}eDEVICE_SM_STATE;
```

If this is not possible by a plugin, I could use external programs just name me a few.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I've found an external program that can do what I am looking for:
http://universalindent.sourceforge.net/

It is not an Eclipse plugin, but at least it can move the coma (and lots of other things).